# Updating code to use dojo 1.6

Tags: dojo, migration

I am new to Dojo and was working on a project anticipating that the dojo will be 1.8. Looks like I have to move to dojo 1.6. I would appreciate how to change my code to 1.6

```
    require(["dojo/request","dojo/ready", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct","dojo/_base/array", "dojo/json","dojo/io-query","dojo/domReady!"],
function(request,ready,dom, domConst, arrayUtil,json,ioQuery){
ready(function(){
```

is how I start coding on 1.8. How do I do this in 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "old dojo" tutorials are still accessible at
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/?ver=1.6 (look at the select box on the top, specifying version)

Legacy dojo loader used dojo.require and dojo.provide functions.
Code taken from this tutorial (http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/hello_dojo/)

```
<!-- load Dojo -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<script>
    // New: Require in the dojo.fx module
    dojo.require("dojo.fx");

    // Remember, dojo.ready waits for both the DOM and all dependencies
    dojo.ready(function(){
        // The piece we had before - change our innerHTML
        dojo.byId("greeting").innerHTML += ", from " + dojo.version;
        // Now, slide the greeting
        dojo.fx.slideTo({
            top: 100,
            left: 200,
            node: dojo.byId("greeting")
        }).play();

    });
</script>
```

Anyway, I would strongly recommend you to upgrade to newer versions of dojo.